# Navigation item hides when clicked

Tags: android

[image: navigation item when selected]

here is the screen shot of my navigation drawer and below are my dependencies which i am using

```
   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
```

these are my dependencies

Comment: It seems you are having some selection/color issues in your code

Comment: please change your item selected color of nevigationdrawer like"app:itemBackground="@color/drawer_item" and put it as in navigation drawer.

Comment: thanx guys you comments really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Change the color in Navigation Drawer's OnClick().

Answer (score 0):

here was color problem i just used the same colors in app theme i just changed the colors and added (
    app:itemIconTint="@color/text_color_white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/text_color_white")
this code to navigation view's xml.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        **app:itemIconTint="@color/text_color_white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/text_color_white"**
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```